# Obtain all unknown event handlers for unbinding and rebinding

Tags: jquery

We are using JQuery 1.4.4 and cannot upgrade yet for some reasons.

I need to obtain all event handlers of an element so I can unbind them and rebind them later on. Something like this:

```
var event_handlers = obtainAllEvenHandlers($('#elem'));
$('#elem').unbind();
...
// Do many things
...
...
for(...) { // Or $.each(event_handlers, ...function() {
  // Note 1: How to obtain the event handler?
  var event_handler = getEventHandler($(this)); // Or just $(this)?
  // Note 2: How to obtain the event from event handler? To know if blur, click, etc
  var e = getEventFromEventHandler($(this));
  $('#elem').bind(e, event_handler);
}
```

Also, how to know the event `e` from the event handler to bind them back later on? Please see **Note 1** and **Note 2**.

```
$('#elem').bind(e, event_handler);
```

Please let me know in comments if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :-

```
jQuery('#elem').data( "events" );
```

The result from `$('..').data('..')` will be an object that contains the events.

OR(as you are using older jquery version),try this :

```
$.each($("#elem").data("events"), function(i, event) {
    alert(i);
    $.each(event, function(j, h) {
        alert(h.handler);
    });
});
```

In order to bind event back use `.bind()` as shown :-

```
$('#elem').bind('eventname',function(){
  // ... code
});
```

Comment: That second one was the one I saw in other answers. So I added `h.handler` to an array `event_handlers`. How to bind each of them back?

Comment: @NeigylR.Noval...for binding event back use ... `$('#elem').bind('eventname',function(){..})`

Comment: how to know `'eventname'` from `event_handlers`? Due to architecture of our code, there can be more than 1 events. Please see edits of my question. Thanks.

Comment: @NeigylR.Noval...`alert(i)` which i have shown in my answer is the event then you can use `i` in place `eventname`.